# Publishing ASP.NET MVC 5 to Windows Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure

I use MVC 5. It also uses entity framework 6.I have two DbContext classes. One for my models and the other for the Identity models. When I want to create a Web App on Microsoft Azure , I faced to this Error . What should I do?

[image]

or when I use to import publish Profile and then I want to connect database in Azure I faced to this Error :

[image]

Currently the application work with SQL DB how should I change it to work with azure sql Db ,what are the steps...I can't connect to Database that I created in Azure . Any Help?

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Well for the second error you could start by following one of many many connectivity troubleshooting guides like this one https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/10085/troubleshooting-connectivity-issues-with-microsoft-azure-sql-database

Comment: I did step by Step thing that come in this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connectivity-issues  ,   but still I have that Error in Sconde Pic

Comment: Can you start a command prompt and type `telnet <server name> 1433`. What happens? Which client connection protocols are enabled when you check using client network utility (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190425(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: @nick-mcdermaid Thank u . it works :)